# Reading the Megillah on Friday

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I accidentally read the Megillah tonight for my shul since last year, I could have sworn, that we read the Megillah right after the fast. Yet, the Rav of the Shul returned from a business trip after the reading and told us that we erred since Purim cannot be celebrated on Fridays, it is נדחה (pushed off) until Sunday.

The question is: Should we repeat the Megillah tomorrow (Friday day) as well? I am compelled to read tomorrow, since the reason for reading during the day and night is because the Jews screamed out when they were in need by day and night (Rashi) - I do not want onlookers to think that they only screamed out during the night.

What do you think?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: This actually makes for an interesting real question, in terms of the groups of people who are supposed to read a few days early, cf Mishna Megillah 1:1.

Comment: Also, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Consider [editing](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/1337) your username to something more meaningful, unless you have some special attachment to 821863. A _Freilichin Purim_ and I look forward to seeing you around!

Answer (score 0):

Since the megillah is read to celebrate the victory, you cannot read it before the fighting is over. This year, the fighting takes place on Shabbos (because of Pikuach nefesh) so we cannot read the megillah until we have won, which would be after Shabbos. Of course when the goyim see you fasting on Thursday, they will be on their guard on Friday and be caught by surprise on Shabbos.